# website 404 Not Found from some locations

Tags: apache, web, nginx, caching, http-status-code-404

I have migrated a website from physical server running apache to a virtual machine running nginx.

When I go to website direct link, website is up : http://www.via-ap.com

but when I go to Google and if I click on website on right panel, I get a 404 error.

[image: see picture here]

see below :

> https://www.google.fr/search?ei=Ri3jW4TXDZGalwSL46vQAQ&q=via+ap&oq=via+ap&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4929.5483.0.5646.6.5.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.0.0....0.76V4PDLEtNM

I did these tests from many browsers and from private mode.

my default nginx vhost conf is :

```
server {
server_name _;
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl default_server;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
return 404;
}
```

and then each website have his own conf like this below :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.website.com website.com;
    root /home/website/www/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/website.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website.error_log info;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-website.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf/website.conf; /* file where strict transport security headers are defined */

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/chain.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf/ssl.conf;
}
```

Do you know why?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Bonjour!  When you position your mouse cursor on the "Site Web" button, what address does it show in the bottom address bar?  Is it what you expect?  The error might be there and not  your server.

Comment: when mouse is over button, the right link is displayed....that's why this is crazy :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found.
on first server block (listen 80)

- as you said first, I have added **www.website.com** in addition to **website.com**
- then I have replaced **return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;** by **return 301 https://$host$request_uri;**